# Passing list to a function to fill the list with variable number of members in C

Tags: c, arrays, list, pointers, realloc

I have written code to generate a list of (x, y, z) coordinates of a given length. The code functions if I generate this list in a main function, but passing a pointer to the list into a fill_xyz_list function produces a runtime error. Presumably there is an issue with dynamic memory allocation or pointers, but I can't find it!

What is the correct way to do this?

Background:
I am trying to generate a walk cycle trajectory for a robotic leg, consisting of a finite list of (x, y, z) coordinates. As the trajectory resolution is dynamic, the list is of unknown length.

The following code produces a runtime error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// core data structure
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

// function that allocates space for our array and fills it with dummy values
void fill_xyz_list(struct Point **xyz_list_ptr, int list_size)
{
    // allocate memory for 100 Point structs
    *xyz_list_ptr = realloc(*xyz_list_ptr, sizeof(struct Point)*list_size);

    // set values for each member
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<list_size; i++)
    {
        xyz_list_ptr[i]->x = i + 0.1;
        xyz_list_ptr[i]->y = i + 0.2;
        xyz_list_ptr[i]->z = i + 0.3;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Point *xyz_list = NULL; // our array of (x, y, z)
    int list_size; // our array size
    int i;

    // set list size
    list_size = 10;

    // fill xyz_list array with dummy values
    fill_xyz_list(&xyz_list, list_size);

    // print all members
    for (i=0; i<list_size; i++)
    {
        printf("xyz_list[%d]: x=%.2f, y=%.2f, z=%.2f\n", i, xyz_list[i].x, xyz_list[i].y, xyz_list[i].z);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `xyz_list_ptr[i]->x = i + 0.1;` should be raising warnings.  Save time, enable the warnings on your compiler.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
xyz_list_ptr[i]->x = i + 0.1;
```

should be

```
(*xyz_list_ptr)[i].x = i + 0.1;
```

Otherwise you are interpreting `xyz_list_ptr` as an array of pointers instead of interpreting it as a pointer to an array, which it really is.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/vxAJeK)

**Note:** Assigning `realloc` back to the pointer being reallocated could lead to memory leaks. You should assign it to a temporary, check it for `NULL`, and only then assign the temporary to the original pointer:

```
struct Point *tmp = realloc(*xyz_list_ptr, sizeof(struct Point)*list_size);
if (!tmp) {
    ... // deal with allocation failure
    ... // exit the function
}
*xyz_list_ptr = tmp;
```

Comment: How, exactly, would you "deal with allocation failure"? That is, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes This depends on an applications. Some would exit, some would stop allocating additional memory, some (more advanced) would free some memory and try again. All of this is well beyond the topic of this question, though - I just wanted to point out the realloc pattern that may be responsible for memory leaks.